# Trigger doesn't run when value of a column changes from null to 1

Tags: mysql, datatypes

I have this trigger:

```
delimiter $$

create trigger tr 
after update on t1
for each row
begin

  if new.col1 !=old.col1 
    then update t2 set col2 =1 where t2.col3=t1.col3;
  end if;

end

$$
```

This trigger works when `col1`'s value changes from 0 to 1 but
when its changes from null to 1, the trigger doesn't make any changes in `t2`.

I just wanted to know why it is so. I know null is different, but I'm just comparing the values.

I have solved my problem by doing `new.col1 =1`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change the if condition to:

```
if (new.col1 != old.col1) or ( new.col1 is not null and old.col1 is null )
                          or ( old.col1 is not null and new.col1 is null )
```

That should solve your problem. The original code didn't work correctly as you can't  test for equality with a `NULL` value - you have to use `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL`.

MySQL has also a "null-safe equals" operator: `<=>` which can be used here to make the above condition simpler (and still equivalent):

```
if not (new.col1 <=> old.col1)
```

Comment: The null-safe comparison operator (`<=>`) might be a better choice.

Answer (score 3):

```
IF !(NEW.col1 <=> OLD.col1)
    THEN UPDATE t2 SET col2 = 1 WHERE t2.col3 = t1.col3;
END IF;
```

Explanation:

**<=>** is a null safe operator, from the MySQL manual:

```
mysql> SELECT 1 <=> 1, NULL <=> NULL, 1 <=> NULL;
        -> 1, 1, 0
mysql> SELECT 1 = 1, NULL = NULL, 1 = NULL;
        -> 1, NULL, NULL
```

Beware though, that this trigger will fire also when `col1`'s value changes from 1 to `NULL`, don't know if that is what you want.

You could rewrite the condition this way, if you don't want this behavior:

```
IF (!(NEW.col1 <=> OLD.col1) AND NEW.col1 IS NOT NULL)
    THEN UPDATE t2 SET col2 = 1 WHERE t2.col3 = t1.col3;
END IF;
```

Answer (score 0):

This makes the inequality case sensitive

```sql
IF NOT(BINARY NEW.col1 <=> BINARY OLD.col1) 
    THEN UPDATE t2 SET col2 = 1 WHERE t2.col3 = t1.col3;
END IF;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ifnull to check and compare. Below are the example with the assumption that you won't have 'xxxxxx' as the real data.

```
delimiter $$

create trigger tr 
after update on t1
for each row
begin

  if (ifnull(new.col1,'xxxxxx') != ifnull(old.col1,'xxxxxx')) 
    then update t2 set col2 =1 where t2.col3=t1.col3;
  end if;

end

$$
```